# WPF Conditional Data Binding

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF grid bound to the following class:

```
public class Output{
    public string TaskName { get; private set; }
    public string Log { get; set; }
}
```

Grid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="viewdetails">view...</sys:String>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Task" Binding="{Binding TaskName}" />
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Log" 
    ContentBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewdetails}}" >
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="ViewLogClick" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Log is a hyperlink column, on click on the link it show the contents of the log file in a new window.

Is it possible to hide the log link if Output.Log is empty?

Comment: What's your itemsource bound to for your DataGrid?

Comment: Could you not just return string.empty for viewDetails if the log is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

I have created a new property and bound the hyperlink column to LogLink as a workaround:

```
private string _log;
public string Log
    {
        get { return _log; }
        set 
        { 
            _log = value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                LogLink = "view...";
            }
        }
    }
    private string _logLink;
    public string LogLink
    {
        get
        {
            return _logLink;
        }
        set
        {
            _logLink = value;
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("LogLink");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding TargetNullValue to your column Binding.

```
 <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Log" 
    ContentBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewdetails}, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}">
```